$n$-th derivative of $(x^2-1)^n$ in powers of $x$
In here I can see that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$ is given in closed form using products of terms $x-1$ and $x+1$.
Is it possible to rewrite this expansion in terms of $x$ only?
The formula given here claims that it is possible (assuming $m=0$) but it seems that it has mistakes (e.g. for $m=0, l=1$)

Why not write with the binomial theorem?

@SeanRoberson what do you mean? the original post that I have linked to already done that isn't it?

The formula you cited is recursive, but you wants a non-recursive formula.
According to the Binomial theorem:
$$(x^2-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{2(n-k)}(-1)^k$$
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(n-2k+1)_nx^{n-2k}$$
$(n-2k+1)_n$ is the pochhammer symbol.
Maple gives:
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n=$$
$$\frac{(-2)^n}{(-1-n)!}x^{-n}\text{MeijerG}\left(^{[0,\frac{1}{2},n+1],[\ ]}_{[0],[\frac{1}{2}n+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}n]}\Big|-x^2\right)$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^n}{(-n)!}x^{-n}\text{hypergeom}\left(^{\frac{1}{2},1,-n}_{-\frac{1}{2}n+1,-\frac{1}{2}*n+\frac{1}{2}},x^2\right)$$
